# How can I use Perl's system call to spawn independent threads?

Tags: perl, multithreading

I would like to call other Perl scripts in order to perform a contention test from with a main Perl script.

Something like this currently works:

```
system("perl 1.pl");
system("perl 2.pl");
exit;
```

However, I would like to kick these off as independent threads running at the same time.

I tried, based on my Google searches, doing something like this:

```
system(1, "perl 1.pl");
system(1, "perl 2.pl");
exit;
```

That doesn't work. The main script exists immediately, which is fine, but the underlying threads I want to spawn don't get kicked off. I was wondering if there was something else I have to do or if anyone else has done something like this.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Do you want threads or processes?  Perl's `system()` function is creating a sub-process (and awaiting its completion before executing the next Perl statement.  These calls to `system(1, ...)` don't look like anything meaningful (fork(), then execve() some alleged program named "1" with an argument of "perl ...").

If you want sub-processes, remove the "threads" tag from this question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
use threads;
$thr1 = threads->create('msc', 'perl 1.pl');
$thr2 = threads->create('msc', 'perl 2.pl');

$thr1->join();
$thr2->join();

sub msc{ ## make system call
  system( @_ );
}
```

This will wait for both to finish executing before the it will exit. I'm guessing this is what you want from your original question, right? If not feel free to drop a comment and edit your post to explain it better, and I'll try again.

Comment: You should really use `$^X` instead of counting on `perl` being in the PATH.

Comment: It's not to hard to divine from context, but I looked up $^X: under use English it is $EXECUTABLE_NAME - "The name used to execute the current copy of Perl"

Answer (score 4):

You can [`fork`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fork.html) off processes to run the commands for you.  If you do, you will probably want to use [`exec`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html) instead of [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

die "could not fork: $!" unless defined (my $first_pid = fork);

#first child
exec $^X, "1.pl" unless $first_pid;

die "could not fork: $!" unless defined (my $second_pid = fork);

#second child
exec $^X, "2.pl" unless $second_pid;

waitpid $first_pid,  0;  #wait for first child to finish
waitpid $second_pid, 0;  #wait for second child to finish
```

See also: [`$^X`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%5eX) and [`waitpid`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/waitpid.html)

Answer (score 3):

Use the fork command to do this, or do it from a shell script.  The shell script (unix only) would look something like:

```
nohup perl 1.pl &
nohup perl 2.pl &
exit
```

And the perl command would look like:

```
if ( ! fork() )
{
    system("perl 1.pl");
}
if ( ! fork() )
{
    system("perl 2.pl");
}
```

There are better ways to do this, meaning write the contention in one script using perl, but this will work.  Make sure that in your parent script you add in a SIG_CHLD function with wait() in it.  You can find more on this kind of event handling out there.  While system("perl 1.pl &"); might work (I haven't tested it), I think that forking and waiting is too valuable a resource not to mention.

Comment: You might as well fork then exec.

Comment: can you even do these kind of things on "foriegn" platforms?  Though I do think it is right to use exec instead of system if your going for fork, since they are used hand-in-hand in most cases. I would say use a module but someone already said it :)

Comment: Discussing "foreign" platformats, Windows is really the main oddball.  There is a section here http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfork.html that discusses the fact that fork is emulated on Windows, but almost all other systems worth discussing perl-wise are Unix variants of some type (Max/Linux/etc.).  System is a little weird, in that you might need to construct different system calls for different systems.  Since writing this, I have changed almost exclusively to using open(,"-|",) for most calls, or open2/open3/select.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Parallel::ForkManager](http://search.cpan.org/~dlux/Parallel-ForkManager-0.7.5/ForkManager.pm) on CPAN - provides a neater interface to threading, which should do exactly what you're looking to do ;)