# Can existing Perl/CGI scripts be called by an already started instance of Perl?

Tags: perl, performance, startup, threadpool

The purpose is to eliminate startup delay for the script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you might want to check out [mod_perl](http://perl.apache.org/) or [FastCGI](http://www.fastcgi.com/mod_fastcgi/docs/mod_fastcgi.html).

Answer (score 1):

The Perl statement [`do`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html) will read a file and execute it. So `do file.pl` will execute the Perl file in `file.pl`.

As stated in [*How can I use Perl's system call to spawn independent threads?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380516/how-can-i-use-perls-system-call-to-spawn-independent-threads), you can also do this with threads, fork, or system.

Answer (score 0):

Also look at [Plack](http://plackperl.org/) with [CGI::PSGI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI%3a%3aPSGI).