# using perl open a new command prompt in parallel and execute a file in it

Tags: perl, fork, multiprocessing, command-prompt

From within the execution of a perl file(say main.pl), I want to create a new command prompt(windows os) and execute a file (say sub.pl) in it, in parallel to the execution of main.pl.

I think I may need to fork a new process for this and call a system() command from the new process. But, I can't figure out this system(...) command which would invoke a new terminal with a new file running and possibly closing as the execution of 'sub.pl' completes.

Please help.

Comment: Have a look on this Question / Answer, it's similar: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1380516/1358866

Comment: @int2000 well, I want to have the new process in a new terminal, also, the posts there just answer the first part.

Comment: Hmm, thats a Windows-Issue. What about Windoze-built-in-Functions like this: `my $cmd = "perl -w otherscript.pl";
my $result = system( "start /LOW $cmd" );`

Comment: ikegami is right. Remove the /LOW. And: Please don't 4get to vote :D

Comment: I don't see any option for voting on a comment...you may rather make it an answer that I would mark as accepted.

Comment: done. You can vote on comments on the left side, above this "flag"-Symbol.

Comment: can't vote you up, I require at least 15 rep to do so

Comment: @int2000       Please could you have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631445/perl-child-process-signaling-parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats a Windows-Issue.

Please try the following:

```
my $cmd = "perl -w otherscript.pl"; 
my $result = system( "start $cmd" );
```

This will open a new "cmd"-Terminal in Windows.