# perl - child process signaling parent

Tags: perl, fork, multiprocessing, signals, kill

I have written the following piece of code to test signaling between child and parent. Ideally, when the child gives a SIGINT to parent the parent should come back in the new iteration and wait for user input. This I have observed in perl 5.8, but in perl 5.6.1(which I am asked to use) the parent is actually "killed". There is no next iteration.

```
my $parent_pid = $$;
$pid = fork();
if($pid == 0)
{   
    print "child started\n";
    kill 2, $parent_pid;
}
else
{
    while(1)
    {
        eval
        {
            $SIG{INT} = sub{die "GOTCHA";};
            print 'inside parent'."\n";
            $a = <>;
        };
        if($@)
        {
                print "got the signal!!!!\n$@\n";
                next;
        }
    }

}
```

Could someone please give a walkaround for this problem or some other way to signal the parent so that it enters the new iteration.

Comment: Sry, can't reproduce it.

Comment: Windows has neither `fork` nor signals.  Those are unix concepts. Perl emulates them. Your problems stem from that.

Comment: Yes, the fork() and signals emulation gets better with more recent versions of Perl on windows. You might want to use the Windows synchronization objects directly from Win32::IPC .

Answer (score 3):

The failure on 5.6.X might be because of the way Perl used to handle signals, which was fixed with ['Safe Signal Handling' in Perl 5.8.0](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perl-5.8.0/pod/perldelta.pod#Safe_Signals). In either case, you are using a Perl which is practically archaeological and you should argue strongly to your masters that you should be using at least Perl 5.12, and ideally 5.14.

Answer (score 2):

This is likely to be a race condition, caused by the child sending the `SIGINT` before the parent was ready for it. Remember that after you `fork()` you will have two independent processes, each might proceed at whatever pace it likes.

It's best in your case to set up the `SIGINT` handler before the `fork()` call, so you know it's definitely in place before the child tries to `kill()` its parent.

(with some minor corrections):

```
$SIG{INT} = sub { die "GOTCHA" };

my $parent_pid = $$;
defined( my $pid = fork() ) or die "Cannot fork() - $!";

if($pid == 0)
{   
    print "child started\n";
    kill INT => $parent_pid;
}
else
{
    while(1)
    {
        eval
        {
            print "inside parent\n";
            <>;
        };
        if($@)
        {
            print "got the signal!!!!\n$@\n";
            next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: while trying different things, I ensured that there was no race condition by appropriately using 'sleeps'. Anyways, that could well have been the reason.